# How to compute azimuth between QgsPointV2s?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, azimuth

The [QgsPoint](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPoint.html) class has an azimuth() method but the new [QgsPointV2](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPointV2.html) class does not. What's the best way to compute the azimuth between QgsPointV2s? I couldn't find a convenient way to convert V2 to the old version, so my fallback is to construct a QgsPoint from the V2's x and y:

```
self.traj = QgsLineStringV2(...)    
p_i = self.traj.pointN(self.i) # this returns a QgsPointV2
p_j = self.traj.pointN(self.j)
a = QgsPoint(p_i.x(),p_i.y()).azimuth(QgsPoint(p_j.x(),p_j.y()))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`azimuth()` has been added to QgsPointV2 in a [recent commit from 2016-11-05](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/983fe24806b47d4c8a9aa6d226685be3fb8de90f).

Guess I'll stick to the code outlined in the question until this change appears in the releases.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simple Euclidean function :

```
def azimuth(point1, point2):
      #interval 0-180° here
      angle = math.atan2(point2.x() - point1.x(), point2.y()-point1.y())     
      return math.degrees(angle) if angle > 0 else math.degrees(angle) + 180 

a = QgsPoint(10,12)
b = QgsPoint(20,30)
azimuth(a,b)
29.054604099077146
```

but

```
a.azimuth(b)
29.054604099077146
```

still works in my case ([double QgsPoint::azimuth(const QgsPoint & other) const](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPoint.html#af93612b99517efb1f75ea2ac58a3657d))

(QGIS from [Nightly Mac Build of QGIS from 'master' Branch](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/))

Comment: Yes, QgsPoint.azimuth() exists but there's no QgsPointV2.azimuth(). I'll probably take your solution and write my own function if there is no convenient way around.