# How to calculate angle between two points and vertical

Tags: pyqgis, angles

Is there an easy method to calculate angle between two points and vertical with PyQGIS ? 
In QGIS I use Cad-Tools extension, I select two points and it give me an azimuth. Now I would like to do the same in my script where i'm already able to select two points.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to compute azimuth between QgsPointV2s?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216495/how-to-compute-azimuth-between-qgspointv2s)

Comment: @Joseph I don't understand how to import/call azimuth fonction. Apparently, it inclues in QgisPoint library. How can I import it ?

Comment: You could use `QgsPoint.azimuth(a,b)` :)

Comment: I finaly used `b.azimuth(a)`. I tryed `azimuth(a,b)` but it didn't work, don't know why...